# understanding bytecode java

Tags: java, exception, jvm, bytecode

Is it possible to read or identify what class is being referenced by the INVOKESPECIAL instruction from java bytecode? If yes, how? Also, how do I know what will be the next line executed after a jump?

Keep in mind that I wanna make a program that do this. What I'm trying to do is find a way to automaticaly localize exception handling through the bytecode alone.

Comment: Exception handling is located in the exception tables, which list the redirections from normal excution to catch blocks.

Comment: What do you mean which class? Do you mean the class/interface that the method is first defined on, or the method that actually gets invoked?

Comment: well, if there is a I/O exception the I/O exception class will be invoked, right? I want to know that was this class that was invoked

Comment: If you have the location of where the exception was thrown then you can examine the invokespecial bytecode to see which class is being initialised. If you only have where the exception was caught then you will only be able to detect the type of the exception and not its class (eg. `IOException` vs `FileNotFoundException`).

Answer (score 1):

you can check this framework about http://asm.ow2.org/. "The ASM framework is the fastest, most flexible and well known framework around for doing bytecode manipulation"

Comment: the ASM framework show the bytecode to me, but how exactly can my program read what the framework says?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of framework them out [there](http://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries) for bytecode manipulation. But I personally prefer [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/index.html). It's XML-parsing like mechanism is a lot easier to learn.

For example, you can use this code to list all `INVOKESPECIAL` callings in a jar file:
It will print lines like this:

`INVOKESPECIAL[ opcode=183, owner=java/lang/StringBuilder, name=<init>, desc=()V]`.

You can say it is the `<init>` function of `java/lang/StringBuilder` that is referenced by `INVOKESPECIAL`.

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("xxx.jar");
Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();

while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry jarEntry = entries.nextElement();
    if (jarEntry != null && jarEntry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
        InputStream eis = jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry);
        ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(eis);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
        MyClassVisitor mcw = new MyClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM4, cw);
        classReader.accept(mcw, 0);
        eis.close();
    }
}


class MyClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
private int api;
public MyClassVisitor(int api, ClassWriter cw) {
    super(api, cw);
    this.api = api;
}
@Override
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
    return new MyMethodVisitor(api, mv);
}
class MyMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {

    public MyMethodVisitor(int api, MethodVisitor mv) {
        super(api, mv);
    }
    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) {
        if (opcode == Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL) {
            System.out.println("INVOKESPECIAL[ opcode=" + opcode + ", owner=" + owner + ", name=" + name
                    + ", desc=" + desc+"]");
        }
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: how can I do that receiving a block of code instead of a jar file?

Comment: You need to compile that block of code to `.class` file. Then you can give it to `ClassReader`!

Comment: Ok, but what if I'm receiving bytecode instruction per bytecode instruction, can I just give these instructions one at a time to the ClassReader and it will work?

Comment: No, I think that is not possible with `ClassReader`. Can you elaborate that, please? From where and in what order are you getting this instructions? Isn't it possible to harvest received instructions into `.class` file?

Comment: I have a program that get bytecode and divide it in blocks. What I need to do is identify which blocks has exception handling, so I thought that I could just search each instruction from each block to find invokespecial instructions and then see if these invokespecial are invoking some exception handling class.
I just don't know exactly how to implement this

Comment: If you can paste your code of separation into blocks, It would be helpful.

Comment: I could not find the creation of the blocks, but as far as I know each block is just a double linked list of nodes that represent bytecode instructions. The program uses asm types like InsnList and such. The blocks are problably delimited by labels.<br/>
Here's the constructor:<br/>
    public basicBlock(InsnList insn) {<br/>
  this.methodInsn = insn;<br/>
  this.loop(-1);<br/>
 }<br/>
The program also verify if the block is a loop.